# Displaying a in-place written html page in the browser

Tags: java, network-programming

In general, I'm working on a webcrawler in Java that gets a domain name from the user and get statistics about this domain, and should return the result as a webpage.
The order of action should be like this:

- Web server opens default page in the browser, that has a form that asks the domain name
- Web crawler is activated, a message in the browser is displayed to indicate so
- Web crawler should return a html result page to the browser

My question (which I'm aware of the fact that it's very general) is how am I doing the 3rd step? The browser and the webcrawer, for the server, are two different clients, so how one can affect the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server should initiate the web crawler process, one for every client. The web crawler is in that case just a server-side variable, the server could capture the output and send it to the client.

Comment: so am i understanding this correctly:  you want to send each crawled page to a browser and open it by the daemon you are building?

Comment: @foampile I crawl the entire domain, and the page of results I would like to send it to the browser

Comment: what do you mean by "send it to the browser"?  open the browser and load the page?  what if there are a lot of finds?